# C++ multithread HTTP Server - recv() hangs up after first sending first response

Tags: c++, multithreading, httpserver

I'm trying to build a multithread HTTP server using C++ and winsock2.h and sys/socket.h.However, after sending response successfully to first request, accept() function captures other requests  and sends through thread pool but those threads hangs up in recv() function so function can never capture data from socket.Here is my code.

```
void HTTPServer::init()
{

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(0x202,&wsaData);

    if((mSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
#else
    if((mSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
#endif
    {
        std::cout << "Error while initilazing socket\n";
    }

    mServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    mServerAddr.sin_port = htons(mPort);
#ifdef _WIN32
    mServerAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
#else
    mServerAddr.sin_addr.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
#endif

    if(bind(mSock, (struct sockaddr*) &mServerAddr, sizeof(mServerAddr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while binding socket\n";
    }

    if(listen(mSock, SOMAXCONN))
    {
        std::cout << "Error while listening socket\n";
    }

}
void HTTPServer::fRun()
{
    ThreadPool* tPool = new ThreadPool(10);
    while(1)
    {
        int size = sizeof(mClientAddr);
#ifdef _WIN32
        if((mAcceptSocket = accept(mSock,(struct sockaddr*) &mClientAddr,&size)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
#else
        if((mAcceptSocket = accept(mSock,(struct sockaddr*) &mClientAddr,&size))) < 0)
#endif
        {
            std::cout << "Error while initilazing accept socket\n";
        }

    
        std::cout << "Socket Sent " << mAcceptSocket << std::endl;
        tPool->enqueue([&] { this->fOnRequest(mAcceptSocket); });

    }
    delete tPool;
}
void HTTPServer::fOnRequest(uint64_t socket)
{
    const string reqData = fRecieveNext(mAcceptSocket);
    const HTTPResponse res = fProcessRequest(reqData);
    fSendResponse(res,socket);
    std::cout << "Done";
}
const string HTTPServer::fRecieveNext(uint64_t socket)
{
    int64_t recieveLength = 0,totalRecieved = 0; 
    int64_t recieveLengthBeforeBody = -1;
    int contentLength = 0;
    string rawData;
    while(1)
    {
        memset(mBuffer,'\0',8192);

        if((recieveLength = recv(socket,mBuffer,8192, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Error while receiving data from socket\n";
#ifdef _WIN32
            std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
#endif
            break;
        }


        if(recieveLength == 0)
            break;
        
        totalRecieved += recieveLength; 
        rawData += string(mBuffer,recieveLength);

        if(totalRecieved > 32)
        {
            if(rawData.find("Content-Length") == string::npos && contentLength == 0)
                break;
            else
            {
                if(contentLength == 0)
                {
                    auto pos = rawData.find("Content-Length:");
                    auto lengthStr = rawData.substr(pos + 16, rawData.find_first_of("\r",pos) - pos - 16);
                    contentLength = std::stoi(lengthStr);
                }
                if(rawData.find("\r\n\r\n") != string::npos && recieveLengthBeforeBody == -1)
                {
                    recieveLengthBeforeBody = rawData.find("\r\n\r\n") + 4;
                }

                if(totalRecieved >= contentLength + recieveLengthBeforeBody)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return rawData;
}
void HTTPServer::fSendResponse(const HTTPResponse& response,const uint64_t socket)
{
    string resStr = response.fSerializeResponse();
    size_t sent = 0,totalSent = 0;
    char* buffer = &(resStr[0]);

    while(totalSent < resStr.length())
    {
        if((sent = send(socket, buffer, resStr.length() - totalSent,0)) < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error while sending response" << std::endl;
        }

        
        buffer += sent;
        totalSent += sent;
    }

    delete &response;
#ifdef _WIN32
    if(shutdown(socket, SD_BOTH) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while closing socket" << std::endl;
        std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    };
    if(closesocket(socket) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while closing socket" << std::endl;
        std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    };
#else
    if(shutdown(socket, SHUT_RDWR) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while closing socket" << std::endl;
    };
    if(close(socket) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while closing socket" << std::endl;
    };
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting to receive a TCP message all in one recv. TCP doesnt work like that. Tcp is a stream protocol, a message sent to you can be broken into multiple chunks. TCP only guarantees that the bytes will arrive once and in the correct order.

That would make you get out of sync with the input

Comment: So how would be the approach?

Comment: @OzanArmagan have a look at my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+is%3Aanswer+http+pseudo) on how to read HTTP messages (note: most of them are geared toward writing an HTTP client, but the same semantics apply to writing a server, too).